# Exclude certain hosts from Payara Server access log

Tags: glassfish

We have an external load balancer that makes health checks to the application servers. We use conditional logging in our current Apache TomEE server to prevent this activity from filling up the HTTP Access Log.

Since we are migrating to Payara, we would like to know how the same can be done.

Regards,
Jalal

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to vendor support.

Comment: it is not a problem that I am trying to solve, I am merely asking where shall such configuration be done on this server.

Comment: You have a support account with your vendor. Use it. Again, we are not here to do your job for you, which is what you are asking us to do. I will not continue discussing this in comments.